# Method for finding roots of perturbation singular problems

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

So I am confident with finding roots of regular perturbation problems, e.g. $x^{2}+2\epsilon x-4=0$. However, I am getting confused when I have a singular problem, where $\epsilon$ affects the leading behaviour. What is the best method to use when finding roots to singular perturbation problems such as $\epsilon x^{2}+2x-4\epsilon=0$ (I don't know if that example actually works, by the way)?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You may set $x=1/y$ and multiply the equation 
$$\epsilon x^{2}+2x-4=0\tag{1}$$

by $y^2$ and obtain:
$$\epsilon +2y-4 y^2=0\tag{2}$$

This probably answers your question.

But in your original example, $\epsilon$ appears both in the leading order term and trailing order term.  So the above method do not work.

We first rewrite it as:
$$\epsilon (x^{2}-4)+2x=0\tag{4}$$

Then we can solve 
$$x^2-4=y^2+4y$$ 
for x and obtain
$$x=y+2,x=-(y+2)$$
We then substitute $x=y+2$ into (4) and obtain
$$\epsilon ((y+2)^{2}+4(y+2))+2(y+2)=0\tag{5}$$

You may apply the method of treating (1) to treat (5).  You may then do it for the second solution $x=-(y+2)$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response, could you please explain where $x^{2}-4=y^{2}+4y$ comes from? Thank you

Comment: And also, this method gives me the first term for x but how would I find subsequent terms? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem lies in realizing which roots are regular and which roots are singular. In this problem, one of the roots is actually regular: this root is a perturbation of the one root of $2x=0$, i.e. of $x=0$. This occurs in a regime where $\epsilon x^2$ is of smaller order than $2x$, so that the dominant term in the expression $\epsilon x^2+2x-4\epsilon$ is $2x$.

But for fixed $\epsilon$, we can take $x$ so large that the dominant term in $\epsilon x^2+2x-4\epsilon$ is $\epsilon x^2$. In this situation, the equation is badly scaled, so we rescale it, by setting $x=\epsilon^p y$. Here $p<0$ and $y$ is bounded (away from $\pm \infty$ and also away from $0$) as $\epsilon \to 0$. This means that the root is getting larger (in magnitude) as $\epsilon$ is going to zero. If you consider $p=-1$, then you get

$$\epsilon^{-1} y^2 + 2 \epsilon^{-1} y - 4 \epsilon = 0$$

which is equivalent to

$$y^2 + 2y - 4 \epsilon^2 = 0.$$

(We chose $p=-1$ so that the quadratic and linear terms would be of the same order.) The relevant solution to this is a regular perturbation perturbation of the root at $-2$ of the equation $y^2+2y=0$. So the relevant solution is $x=-2\epsilon^{-1}$ plus higher order terms.

Comment: Oh right, I think I follow. Thanks :) My lecturer has never shown us that way. Instead the method he taught us was to find the exact solution to find the leading order behaviour of epsilon, and then write a power series expansion with that as the leading order. This confused me a bit when we got to higher powers of x etc..

Comment: @anon Usually we want to do perturbative expansion without having an expression for the exact solution. In this particular case we can use the exact solution: $x=\frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4 + 16 \epsilon^2}}{2 \epsilon}$. The leading order approximations are given by dropping the $16 \epsilon^2$ term and leaving the rest.

Comment: How would we adapt the above method with an x^3 term?

Comment: for instance, I've got an example here, but if I do the above I get $y^{3}+\epsilon ^{-1}y^{2}+...=0$ , but I'm not sure how to deal with the $\epsilon ^{-1}$ bit?

Comment: @anon What is the starting problem for this cubic equation? (If you have a negative exponent in your equation, you've chosen the wrong scaling.)

Comment: it's $\epsilon ^{4}x^{4}-x^{2}-x+2=0$

Comment: OK: so when $x$ is small enough relative to $\epsilon$, the first term is negligible, and you should see two roots near the roots of the quadratic (which I guess are actually complex). When $x$ is large enough the first two terms should be of the same order. So take $x=\epsilon^p y$, where $p$ is such that $\epsilon^4 x^4$ and $x^2$ have the same power of $\epsilon$ in front of them. In the previous problem that meant $p=-1$; here it means $4p+4=2p$, so I guess $p=-2$.

Comment: sorry, I meant $\epsilon x^{4}-x^{2}-x+2=0$

Comment: OK. First off, I missed a minus sign, so the quadratic piece has real roots. Second, the situation is similar, but because there is no $y^3$ term at all, the proper choice of $p$ is different. But the basic idea is the same: you want $4p+1=2p$ so $p=-1/2$. Thus $x=\epsilon^{-1/2}y$ will find the singular roots.

Comment: so would that lead to $y^{4}-y^{2}+-y\epsilon ^{1/2}+ 2\epsilon=0$ ?thanks

Comment: That's right. ${}{}$

Comment: lovely, thank you very much!

Comment: the only problem is how would we find the second term of the asymptotic expansion for x? Thanks

Comment: For which root? There are four: there are two when $x$ is small (near solutions of the corresponding quadratic) and two when $x$ is large (near $\epsilon^{-1/2}$ times the two nonzero solutions of $y^4-y^2=0$). Let's say you want the one near $\epsilon^{-1/2} \cdot 1$. Plug in $y=1+\delta$, taking $\delta$ to be small, extract the leading order piece from each term, and then choose $\delta$ as a constant times a power of $\epsilon$ in order to eliminate the lowest order terms that you can.

Comment: Some calculational tricks are helpful; for instance $(1+\delta)^4 = 1+4\delta+O(\delta^2)$ (which is just Taylor expansion).